# How can I print out the iskeyword characters?

Tags: cursor-motions

When I use `:set iskeyword?` to view keyword characters, result for shell scripts is:

```
iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,-
```

:h iskeyword says @ expands to any alpha character that the isalpha() functions returns true on, but what about `48-57` and `192-255` how can I view these characters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

```
:echo map(range(48, 57), 'nr2char(v:val)')
:echo map(range(192, 255), 'nr2char(v:val)')
```

Which should output:

> ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
>
> ['À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò',
>   'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', '×', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý', 'Þ', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', '
>   æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ð', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', '÷', 'ø', 'ù
>   ', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'þ', 'ÿ']

To break it down:

- `range(192, 255)` makes a list from 192 to 255.
- `nr2char()` converts a number from its ASCII code to a string.
- `map()` applies `nr2char()` to every item in the list.

Comment: Works great, thanks.  I'm assuming the characters in range (192-255) are not normal ascii. is that some kind of "extended ascii"?

Comment: the_velor_fog: ASCII only has 7bit. Those are Unicode codepoints. You can go much higher than 255.

Comment: I find this helpful for working out the hex equivalent of decimal UTF notation https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec. Choose `Englisch` as the language

Comment: Actually, since I wrote this answer 5 years ago I also made a little CLI tool for this kind of stuff @Steve: https://github.com/arp242/uni; which, to me anyway, seems a lot easier than that website (but I'm probably a bit biased ) You can [even run it in your browser](https://arp242.github.io/uni-wasm/#color:light,run%3Ap%200d48..0d57%200d192..0d255)

Comment: @MartinTournoij oops didn't see the date :( . Ta for tool

Comment: It's fine to comment on old posts @Steve; the entire idea is that answers remain useful in the long term, and are not *only* useful for just the person who asked it here. I've often improved answers from years ago based on comments/feedback.

Answer (score 5):

I went a little overboard… turns out parsing the `isfname` format is hard!

This parses `iskeyword` into a single list of strings. Each string is either a single character (included) or a character preceded by `^` (excluded). Also, the strings `isalpha()` (included) and `^isalpha()` (excluded) stand for all characters accepted by the C function.

You could shorten the range displays if you like with some tweaks. You could also put in `join(',')` and get a comma-separated list.

For example, after `:setlocal iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,-`, we can do

```
:echo ParseIsFnameChars(&l:iskeyword)
['-', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '_', 'isalpha()', 'À', 'Á', 'Â', 'Ã', 'Ä', 'Å', 'Æ', 'Ç', 'È', 'É', 'Ê', 'Ë', 'Ì', 'Í', 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ð', 'Ñ', 'Ò', 'Ó', 'Ô', 'Õ', 'Ö', '×', 'Ø', 'Ù', 'Ú', 'Û', 'Ü', 'Ý', 'Þ', 'ß', 'à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'ä', 'å', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'î', 'ï', 'ð', 'ñ', 'ò', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ö', '÷', 'ø', 'ù', 'ú', 'û', 'ü', 'ý', 'þ', 'ÿ']
```

Here's the function. Suggestions for improvement welcome

```
" The format of this option is a list of parts, separated with commas.
" Each part can be a single character number or a range.  A range is two
" character numbers with '-' in between.  A character number can be a
" decimal number between 0 and 255 or the ASCII character itself (does
" not work for digits).  Example:
"        "_,-,128-140,#-43"      (include '_' and '-' and the range
"                                128 to 140 and '#' to 43)
" If a part starts with '^', the following character number or range
" will be excluded from the option.  The option is interpreted from left
" to right.  Put the excluded character after the range where it is
" included.  To include '^' itself use it as the last character of the
" option or the end of a range.  Example:
"        "^a-z,#,^"      (exclude 'a' to 'z', include '#' and '^')
" If the character is '@', all characters where isalpha() returns TRUE
" are included.  Normally these are the characters a to z and A to Z,
" plus accented characters.  To include '@' itself use "@-@".  Examples:
"        "@,^a-z"        All alphabetic characters, excluding lower
"                        case ASCII letters.
"        "a-z,A-Z,@-@"   All letters plus the '@' character.
" A comma can be included by using it where a character number is
" expected.  Example:
"        "48-57,,,_"     Digits, comma and underscore.
" A comma can be excluded by prepending a '^'.  Example:
"        " -~,^,,9"      All characters from space to '~', excluding
"                        comma, plus <Tab>.
" See |option-backslash| about including spaces and backslashes.

function ParseIsFnameChars(value) abort
  const parts = split(a:value, ',', v:true)
  const num_parts = len(parts)
  let result = []
  let index = 0
  let last_caret = v:false
  for part in parts
    let part_to_parse = substitute(part, '^\^', '', '')
    let part_ends = split(part_to_parse, '-')
    let num_ends = len(part_ends)
    if part_to_parse is# '-' " => num_ends is# 0
      " just -
      let parsed = ['-']
    elseif empty(part_to_parse) " => num_ends is# 0
      let parsed = [',']
    elseif num_ends is# 1
      " single items
      let parsed = [part_to_parse =~# '\d\+'
            \ ? str2nr(part_to_parse)->nr2char()
            \ : part_to_parse is# '@'
            \ ? 'isalpha()'
            \ : part_to_parse]
    elseif num_ends is# 2 && part is# '@-@'
      let parsed = ['@']
    elseif num_ends is# 2 " && part isnot# '@-@'
      let left_end_parsed = part_ends[0] =~# '\d\+'
            \ ? str2nr(part_ends[0])
            \ : char2nr(part_ends[0])
      let right_end_parsed = part_ends[1] =~# '\d\+'
            \ ? str2nr(part_ends[1])
            \ : char2nr(part_ends[1])
      let parsed = range(left_end_parsed, right_end_parsed)->map({_, v -> nr2char(v)})
    else
      throw "ParseIsFnameChars: ".part." is not formatted correctly: wrong number of subparts to -"
    endif
    if part =~# '^\^$' && index is# num_parts-1
      " include a '^'
      let result += ['^']
    elseif part =~# '^\^$' " && index isnot# num_parts-1
      " preceding a comma
      let last_caret = v:true
    elseif last_caret
      if empty(part)
        call filter(result, {_, v -> v isnot# ','})
        let result += ['^,']
      else
        throw "ParseIsFnameChars: ".part." is not formatted correctly: non-comma after non-ending ^"
      endif
      let last_caret = v:false
    elseif part =~# '^\^'
      " exclude
      call filter(result, {_, v -> index(parsed, v) >= 0})
      let result += map(parsed, '"^".v:val')
    else
      " include
      let to_remove = mapnew(parsed, '"^".v:val')
      call filter(result, {_, v -> index(to_remove, v) < 0})
      let result += parsed
    endif
    let index += 1
  endfor
  return result->sort()->uniq()
endfunction
```

---

Martin and I had the following conversation in chat that I thought was worth preserving:

Martin Tournoij

> @D.BenKnoble Re: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31564/51
> Good grief ...
> That's all I have to say about that 
> Actually, I do have some more to say: something like a `keyword()` function wouldn't be a bad idea; shouldn't be too hard to add to Vim
> That's what I would have done anyway, usually patches like this should get accepted fairly quickly
> And seems like a useful function to have
> e.g. `keyword()` → returns all keyword characters as an array
> Actually seems less effort than that Vim function heh, and the Vim codebase actually isn't as bad as some people make it out to be; some parts are hairy, but a new function is something even a bad C programmer like me can do :-)
> as long as you stay away from the whole screen update stuff and such

D. Ben Knoble

> @MartinTournoij Honestly the function is pretty inefficient because of all the list stuff. Worse though is that it’s not enough to just include all the keyword characters. For one, there’s @ for isalpha; for two, you can exclude characters. I think it would need to turn more information (possibly a dict?). The good news is the vim codebase should already have some logic for parsing iskeyword. (I also may have spotted a bug in my code lol)

Martin Tournoij

> It's `init_chartab()` in `charset.c`, but right now it just sets the values on the buffer directly rather than parsing it in to a struct or some such and using that to set the buffer values, so that would need some rewriting
> I thought I might cook up a quick patch, but this is too much work  Especially since I don't really have a use case for this myself

D. Ben Knoble

> For anyone else: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/4781d6fd8670af415c3b78f00d70036af85bd286/src/charset.c#L150